# Fade out animation when closing a screen with React and CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations

I have a simple page that opens upon clicking a button and covers my entire screen upon opened.

I have it fading in when opening, but would like it to fade out when closing. How could this be done?

It's display is currently controlled from my component's state and I use CSS' keyframe animation.

Here is a sample of what my app currently looks like:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [opened, setOpened] = React.useState(false)
  return (
  <div>
    <button className='btn' onClick={() => setOpened(!opened)}>{opened ? 'Close' : 'Open'}</button>
    <div style={{margin: 50 }}>Some page content that will be covered</div>
<button onClick={() => console.warn('clicked')}>I need to be clickable when visible</button>
    <div className={opened ? 'content': 'no-content'}>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
      <button>I do nothing</button>
      <p>Tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa enim nec dui. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc consequat interdum. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi tristique. Nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus. Sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula. Vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies tristique. Sit amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis. Tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim. Feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu dictum. Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla. Sit amet risus nullam eget. Id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices. Massa tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit. Vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non. Faucibus a pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor morbi. Dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt. Lorem sed risus ultricies tristique. Viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris.
</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.btn {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
    0% { opacity: 1 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
    0% { opacity: 1 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

.no-content {
    opacity: 0;
    animation: fadeOut 500ms linear;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 1 }
}

.content {
    opacity: 1;
    animation: fadeIn 1s linear;
  
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '.no-content'  has display: none

which instantly removes the element and the animation does not take place

I just removed that and it worked just fine.

I added the other CSS to fix the position of the div  'I assumed you want it like this'

```js
const App = () => {
  const [opened, setOpened] = React.useState(false)
  const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
  const handleClick = ()=>{
    setOpened(!opened)
    if(overlay){
      if(!opened) overlay.style.display = "block" 
      else{
         setTimeout(() => {
              overlay.style.display = 'none'
      }, 1000) // animation time
      }
     
    }
  }
  
  return (
  <div>
    <button className='btn' onClick={handleClick }>{opened ? 'Close' : 'Open'}</button>
    <div style={{margin: 50 }}>Some page content that will be covered</div>
    <div id="overlay" className={opened ? 'content': 'no-content'}>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
      <button>I do nothing</button>
      <p>Tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa enim nec dui. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc consequat interdum. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi tristique. Nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus. Sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula. Vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies tristique. Sit amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis. Tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim. Feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu dictum. Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla. Sit amet risus nullam eget. Id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices. Massa tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit. Vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non. Faucibus a pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor morbi. Dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt. Lorem sed risus ultricies tristique. Viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris.
</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.btn {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
    0% { opacity: 1 }
    100% { opacity: 0,
      display: none
    }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 1 }
}


.no-content {
    opacity: 0;
    animation: fadeOut 500ms linear;
    position: absolute;
    
  top:0;
  right:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
 
}


.content {
    opacity: 1;
    animation: fadeIn 1s linear;
  
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I do have a follow up though,  isn't this going to block all other elements that would be covered by the screen? IN your example, I can't even select the text I put in (I presume it is the div which now has opacity 0 covering it). Sorry, I should've been more specific. Not only do I need the screen "invisible", but I would still have other elements that would be covered by it. For all intents and purposes it needs to be completely gone.

Comment: I edited my answer check the new one @theJuls

Answer (score 0):

You dont need animation for that transition is much cleaner

```js
const App = () => {
  const [opened, setOpened] = React.useState(false)
  return ( <
    div >
    <
    button className = 'btn'
    onClick = {
      () => setOpened(!opened)
    } > {
      opened ? 'Close' : 'Open'
    } < /button> <
    div style = {
      {
        margin: 50
      }
    } > Some page content that will be covered < /div> <
    div className = {'content ' +(
      opened ? 'show-content' : '')
    } >
    <
    p >
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <
      /p> <
      button > I do nothing < /button> <
        p > Tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa enim nec dui.Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc consequat interdum.Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi tristique.Nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus.Sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula.Vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies tristique.Sit amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis.Tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim.Feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu dictum.Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla.Sit amet risus nullam eget.Id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices.Massa tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit.Vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus.Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non.Faucibus a pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor morbi.Dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt.Lorem sed risus ultricies tristique.Viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris. <
        /p> <
        /div> <
        /div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render( <
  App / > ,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.btn {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  }





.content {
transition: 0.3s;
  opacity:0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.show-content {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```